# ExactTarget Landing Page form - getting a ExactTarget error message if two non-required fields are empty

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, sobject, sobjecttype, landing-page

I have an ExactTarget Landing page form that create a SF Lead when submitted. If every field is filled out(approx 20 fields) everything passes into SF with no issue. The problem is this - of the non-required fields, two of them give me this generic error upon submission if they are left blank.

**Call to create the salesforceobject Lead failed! Error in the application.**

Here are the two fields:

```
SET @Decision_Date__c = RequestParameter("Decision_Date__c"))<br />
SET @Enrollment__c = RequestParameter("Enrollment__c"))
```

'Decision Date' is set as a Date field in SF. 'Enrollment' is set as a Number.

I've tried using 'IsNullDefault' and setting "" as the default, but no luck so far. Any help appreciated!

**** It looks like it might be something to do with the Data type in Salesforce. If I reassign the problematic variables to TEXT fields in SF the error doesn't occur, although I don't see why this would matter if no value is passed.